# Using XStream for converting overly-complicated XML to Java Object

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I've been using XStream for some simple XML conversions but I got stuck on this one. What I'm trying to do is to create a Java program to read and tweak this kind of XML;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<actor id="id273212" PGFVersion="0.19" GSCVersion="0.10.4">
  <attributes>
    <text id="name">Actor 1c</text>
    <real id="time">0</real>
    <point id="position">
      <real id="x">0</real>
      <real id="y">0</real>
    </point>
    <size id="size">
      <real id="width">120</real>
      <real id="height">120</real>
    </size>
    <angle id="rotation">0</angle>
    <color id="color">
      <real id="red">1</real>
      <real id="green">1</real>
      <real id="blue">1</real>
      <real id="alpha">1</real>
    </color>
    <image id="image" />
    <text id="tags" />
    <boolean id="preloadArt">true</boolean>
  </attributes>
  <behaviors />
  <aspects>
    <graphics>
      <attributes>
        <boolean id="visible">true</boolean>
        <enumeration id="blendingMode">0</enumeration>
        <enumeration id="horizontalWrap">0</enumeration>
        <enumeration id="verticalWrap">0</enumeration>
        <enumeration id="horizontalAnchor">0</enumeration>
        <enumeration id="verticalAnchor">0</enumeration>
        <boolean id="flipHorizontally">false</boolean>
        <boolean id="flipVertically">false</boolean>
        <integer id="tileWidth">0</integer>
        <integer id="tileHeight">0</integer>
      </attributes>
    </graphics>
    <motion>
      <attributes>
        <point id="linearVelocity">
          <real id="x">0</real>
          <real id="y">0</real>
        </point>
        <real id="angularVelocity">0</real>
        <real id="maxSpeed">0</real>
        <boolean id="applyMaxSpeed">false</boolean>
      </attributes>
    </motion>
    <physics>
      <attributes>
        <real id="density">1</real>
        <real id="friction">3</real>
        <real id="restitution">1</real>
        <boolean id="fixedRotation">false</boolean>
        <boolean id="movable">true</boolean>
        <enumeration id="collisionShape">0</enumeration>
        <real id="drag">0</real>
        <real id="angularDrag">0</real>
      </attributes>
    </physics>
  </aspects>
</actor>
```

I can't understand how to do: `<text id="name">Actor 1c</text>`

The closest I could get was:

```
  <text id="name">
    <variables>Actor 1c</variables>
  </text>
```

What I did is, I created a "text" class that accepts a String ("Actor 1c") into 'variables'.

I tried using "addImplicitCollection" but it won't work. I know this question doesn't have a simple answer but how should I build my Java so I can read these XML files?

Comment: Here is how you could map it with JAXB using `@XmlValue`:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html

Comment: @Blaise Doughan I still do not get it. What you describe there is like using `xstream.useAttributeFor(PhoneNumber.class, "type");`

I was already able to do that. And when I had something like `Text text1 = new Text();` in PhoneNumber, I couldn't get it to print out.

Answer (score 0):

To me the hardest part here is a map of `<attributes>` which can store complex objects. In Java this would look as HashMap of objects. Now, your attributes have ids and that would be a key for an entry this hash map. This means you would most probably require custom converters for your XML nodes.

From my experience with such documents, it's not very productive and I always end up studying the XML tool implementation details to understand why it's not working. The other problem is that XML document may become creative at some of it's parts, especially if there is no schema, and this is what's not very welcomed by the tools.

So I would suggest to try parsing this with a StAX parser - to walk the tree and manually convert the nodes. Or to convert it to a DOM tree and then to convert the DOM tree into objects.

Answer (score 0):

XStream's [ToAttributedValueConverter](http://xstream.codehaus.org/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/extended/ToAttributedValueConverter.html) can help you here:

```
@XStreamConverter(value=ToAttributedValueConverter.class, strings={"value"})
@XStreamAlias("text")
public class Text {
  private String value;
  private String id;

  // getters/setters/etc. as appropriate
}
```

The field named by "strings" will be used to store the text content of the element, and the other fields are mapped to attributes.

Comment: Can you please give me a little more details? Should I build -> public ToAttributedValueConverter(Class type,
                          Mapper mapper,
                          ReflectionProvider reflectionProvider,
                          ConverterLookup lookup,
                          String valueFieldName)

Comment: @canberk you shouldn't need to build anything, `ToAttributedValueConverter` is a standard XStream class and putting the `@XStreamConverter` annotation on your class should be enough to activate it.  As always when you're using annotation-based configuration for reading, you will also need to call `xstream.processAnnotations(Text.class)` (and the same for any other classes you have annotated).